# Multi-Threaded applicaiton has poor performace on a machine?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5

I have created a multi-threaded application that runs fine on every system except for one. The system is a windows 7 home edition setup. The 2 systems is running fine on are windows 7 Ultimate.  Instead of each thread running independently, they seem to run in tandem. Also it runs really slow. It is really strange. I think the system is a quad core system and not sure if that has anything to do with it. I know I don’t have any code up here, but I was hoping you all might have some ideas.

Update:
Well, it turned out someone had removed the indexes out of my database. It seemed like the applicaiton was hanging, but it really was having trouble updating the records becuase the PK was removed. Thank all for your thoughts.

Comment: Need a lot more details to even begin to offer a suggestion :)

Comment: So let me recap - System runs slow on Windows 7 Home Edition, but fine on Ultimate. Maybe Threads are not running concurrently ?  Answer - What have you measured ? What software are you running ? What else are you running ? Are the machines on the same network ? What else is different between two machines ? How much RAM is needed by your APP ? Have you tried reducing your code to a bare minimum that can reproduce the problem ?

Comment: I realize there could be a ton of variable, but was curious if anyone may have had a similar issue with a multi-threaded app. I will contuine to see what might be different.

Comment: Are any exceptions thrown? Are you absorbing any exceptions silently?

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question. Go ahead and do that and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was an issue with indexes being removed fromt he database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Windows 7 home basic has a built in limit of a single processor.

Yup:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions

Comment: But Windows Home Premium is not limited in this way - and Home Basic has limited availability.

Comment: But it supports multiple cores, but one physical cpu. If the machine in question is somewhat new, it should either have multiple cores or support hyper-threading.

Comment: Starter edition is definitely single core

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/07/24/windows-7-starter-edition-features-and-restrictions-no-3-running-applications-limit/

The Wikipedia table doesn't reflect that either, so possibly that holds for basic as well.

Comment: Confirmed:
http://www.engadget.com/2009/05/22/microsoft-publishes-maximum-windows-7-netbooks-specs/